# Get values from specific columns in different csv files, concat. and create column based on filename in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple (more than 100) files like this:

filename: 00.csv

```
residue, vwd, total  
AAA,0.00, -9.45  
BBB, 0.45, -1.45  
CCC, 0.44, -3    
DDD, 0.1, -10
```

filename: 01.csv

```
residue, vwd, total  
AAA, 2, -0.56  
BBB, -4, -9.32  
CCC, 2.54, -10  
DDD, 3, -6.4
```

...

I would like to create a matrix in a new csv file where the first column is "residue", and the others are based on filename (without extension). Below filename, it should be values from "total" column. It would be like this:

```
residue, 00, 01, ...      
AAA, -9.45, -0,56, ...  
BBB, -1.45, -9.32, ...  
CCC, -3, -10,...  
DDD,  -10, -6.4, ...
```

.
.
.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
files = ['00.csv', '01.csv']

dfs = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
    df = df[['residue', 'total']].rename({'total': os.path.splitext(file)[0]}, axis=1)
    dfs.append(df)

df = cols[0]
for sub_df in cols[1:]:
    df = df.merge(sub_df, on='residue')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  residue     00     01
0     AAA  -9.45  -0.56
1     BBB  -1.45  -9.32
2     CCC  -3.00 -10.00
3     DDD -10.00  -6.40
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try read the files then `pivot table`

first get all csv files in that dir

```
import os

#current directory
path = "."
file_names = list(filter(lambda x:x.endswith(".csv"),os.listdir(path)))

print(file_names)
```

> ```
> ['filename: 00.csv', 'filename: 01.csv']
> ```

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in file_names:
   df = df.append(pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file),pd.DataFrame([file]*4,
   columns= ["filename"])],axis=1))

# to extract digit from filename
df["filename"] =df["filename"].str.extract('(\d+)')

print(df)
```

> ```
>   residue vwd  total  filename
> 0 AAA    0.00  -9.45  00
> 1 BBB    0.45  -1.45  00
> 2 CCC    0.44  -3.00  00
> 3 DDD    0.10  -10.00 00
> 0 AAA    2.00  -0.56  01
> 1 BBB   -4.00  -9.32  01
> 2 CCC    2.54  -10.00 01
> 3 DDD    3.00  -6.40  01
> ```

Then `pivot_table` will do the job

```
df.pivot_table(values='total', index='residue', columns='filename')
```

Final output:

> ```
> filename  00   01
> residue       
> AAA          -9.45 -0.56
> BBB          -1.45 -9.32
> CCC          -3.00 -10.00
> DDD          -10.00 -6.40
> ```